# Orbit inclination in 3 dimensional space

Tags: javascript, math, 3d

So I'm working at a project where I need to retrieve particles data (might get up to few thousands objects) from the server (in order to sync the clients) and I'm struggling on finding out how is the orbital inclination of multiple particles calculated.

So far I have the orbit total radius, the width (start & end point of the particles)

```
 var asteroidsOrbit = Common.random( 90, 100),
     rotation = Math.PI / 2, // Not sure where to use this yet
     radians = Common.random(0, 360) * Math.PI / 180;
```

I also render the orbit, by setting the positions of the particles where they need to :

```
     position_x: Math.sin(radians) * asteroidsOrbit,
     position_y: Common.random(-10, 10),
     position_z: Math.cos(radians) * asteroidsOrbit
```

I noticed that by default the orbit is perpendicular to the X plane, behaving as it should. 
But how should I apply the `rotation` to it since it might be rotated 20deg on x plane ?

Comment: You can try and use [Rotation Matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_matrix), but if you're having trouble with edge cases (0°, 90° or similar), you might consider [Quaternions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quaternions_and_spatial_rotation). If you are using a rotation matrix remember to [change basis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Change_of_basis) so the vector you're rotating is the correct one (normally the rotation matrices apply to vector [0, 0, 1], so you need to find the basis change from [0,0,1] to whatever vector you want to rotate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've made some code in Python to apply rotations to a particle's speed in 3D space, could be helpful:
[image]

```
def make_rotation_matrix(theta=0.,phi=0.,cos_theta=False,cos_phi=False):
    """
    Returns a rotation matrix for given angles.
    Makes the rotation matrix for a given theta angle around the y axis (polar
    angle) followed by another rotation around the z axis by a given phi angle
    (azimuthal angle).

    Parameters
    ----------
    theta : float
        Polar angle, between 0 and pi (or its cosine between -1 and 1).
    phi : float
        Azimuthal angle, between 0 and 2pi.
    cos_theta : boolean
        Wether to consider theta as an angle (False) or its cosine (True).
    cos_phi : boolean
        Wether to consider phi as an angle (False) or its cosine (True).

    Returns
    ----------
    out : np.array
        Rotation matrix (shape == (3,3)).

    Examples
    --------
    >>> make_rotation_matrix(0,10)
    array([[-0.83907153,  0.54402111, -0.        ],
           [-0.54402111, -0.83907153, -0.        ],
           [-0.        ,  0.        ,  1.        ]])
    >>> make_rotation_matrix(10,0)
    array([[-0.83907153, -0.        , -0.54402111],
           [-0.        ,  1.        , -0.        ],
           [ 0.54402111,  0.        , -0.83907153]])
    >>> make_rotation_matrix(0.1,0,True)
    array([[ 0.1       , -0.        ,  0.99498744],
           [ 0.        ,  1.        ,  0.        ],
           [-0.99498744,  0.        ,  0.1       ]])
    """
    if cos_theta:
        cos_theta = theta
        sin_theta = np.sqrt(1. - cos_theta**2)
    else:
        cos_theta = np.cos(theta)
        sin_theta = np.sin(theta)
    if cos_phi:
        cos_phi = phi
        sin_phi = np.sqrt(1. - cos_phi**2)
    else:
        cos_phi = np.cos(phi)
        sin_phi = np.sin(phi)
    return np.array(
    [[cos_theta*cos_phi ,  -sin_phi  ,  sin_theta*cos_phi],
     [cos_theta*sin_phi ,   cos_phi  ,  sin_theta*sin_phi],
     [     -sin_theta   ,      0     ,  cos_theta        ]])


def skew_symmetric_cross_product(vector):
    """
    Returns the skew symmetric cross product of given vector.

    Parameters
    ----------
    vector : iterable
        Iterable object, must have at least 3 elements, corresponding to
        the vectors x, y and z components.

    Returns
    ----------
    out : np.array
        Skew symmetric cross product of the given vector (shape == (3,3)).

    Examples
    --------
    >>> skew_symmetric_cross_product([1,0,0])
    array([[ 0.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0., -1.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0.]])
    >>> skew_symmetric_cross_product([0,1,0])
    array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.],
           [-1.,  0.,  0.]])
    >>> skew_symmetric_cross_product([0,0,1])
    array([[ 0., -1.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  0.]])
    """
    return np.array([[ 0.         , -vector[2] , vector[1]  ],
                     [ vector[2]  , 0.         , -vector[0] ],
                     [ -vector[1] , vector[0]  , 0.         ]])


def rotation_a2b(a,b):
    """
    Returns the rotation matrix that transforms vector a in b.
    From
    http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/180418/

    Parameters
    ----------
    a : iterable
        Iterable object, must have at least 3 elements, corresponding to
        the vectors x, y and z components.

    b : iterable
        Similar to a.

    Returns
    ----------
    out : np.array
        Rotation matrix that transforms a in b (shape == (3,3)).

    Examples
    --------
    >>> rotation_a2b([1,0,0],[1,0,0])
    array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
    >>> rotation_a2b([1,0,0],[0,1,0])
    array([[ 0., -1.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  0.,  0.],
           [ 0.,  0.,  1.]])
    >>> rotation_a2b([1,0,0],[0,0,1])
    array([[ 0.,  0., -1.],
           [ 0.,  1.,  0.],
           [ 1.,  0.,  0.]])
    """
    if np.all(a==b):
        return np.identity(3)
    v = np.cross(a,b)
    v_sscp = skew_symmetric_cross_product(v)
    s = np.sqrt(np.dot(v,v))
    c = np.dot(a,b)
    return np.identity(3) + v_sscp +\
           (((1-c)/(s**2))*np.dot(v_sscp,v_sscp))
```

Excerpt [edited] from my report:

Because the rotation has be around the particle's velocity (`vp`), the matrix `R` resulting from `make_rotation_marix` can not be directly applied to `vp` - we must first change the basis to make the velocity collinear with the (0, 0, 1) vector, apply the rotation and then change the basis back to the original. As the result of the first base change is known to be (0, 0, sp), sp being the speed of the particle (velocitie's magnitude), the first base change is skipped
and `R` is applied to (0, 0, sp).

To change the basis back we use the matrix which changes (0, 0, 1) back into the initial particle velocity, provided by the function `Rotation_a2b`. The matrix `Ra2b` turns vector `a` into `b`, so it is called with `a` = (0, 0, 1) and `b` equal to the normalised particle's initial velocity. The fact that we normalize the velocity means the change of basis preserves the size of the vectors - alternatively one could use `a` = (0, 0, sp).
[image]

Comment: I kept struggling by doing something similar in pure JS, when I found out that there's a library for NodeJS (math3d) which does exactly what I needed